# Find whether a random number is Prime or not and Store in a character value

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing a game, where it should do below

Randomly generate a number. Check whether it is a Prime or not. Store "y" if its a Prime else "n"

I will ask the user whether it is prime or not. If he answers correctly I will proceed. Otherwise I will say you lost.

Code sample I tried is as follows:

```
cout<<"\n \n a no. of prime no.s will be displaed to you ,you will have to decide if it is prime or not within the given time\n \n ";
char ch1,ch2;
for(int i=1;i<=20;i++)
{
    int a= rand( ) % 20;
    cout<< "The number is:";
    cout<<a;
    for(int l=2;l<=a-1;l++)
    {
        if(a%l==0)
            ch2='n';
        else
            ch2='y';                            
    }

    cout<<ch2;   
    cout<<"\n\n Enter ""y"" If the number is Prime Else Please enter ""n""\n";                       
    cin>>ch1;
    if(ch1 == ' ')
    {
        cout<<"\n \n u lost";
        break;
    }
    else if(ch1==ch2)
        continue;
    else if(ch1!=ch2)
    {
        cout<<"\n \n u lost";
        break;
    }
}
```

My code is not determining whether it is Yes or No. It is everytime storing "Y" only

Comment: Your code will not even compile, much less run.

Comment: Since you are only checking numbers in the range [0, 19], I suggest you simply compare against a hard-coded list.

Comment: You should `break` from loop when you discover the number is not prime.

Comment: what's after last `else` in first `for` loop ?

Comment: I have put that as 19 to test. I will later change to loop to 10000

Comment: Even then you only need the primes up to 100.

Comment: @Yousaf That is where am struck. I couldnt frame code for the logic. I need "y" or "n" at end of the for loop. y if its a prime. n if its not a prime

Comment: You need to break from the loop becaue the last divisor in the loop is `a - 1` which always has a remainder unless `a == 2`

Comment: @Bathsheba I will increase the loop counts. My doubt is only on the "y" or "n" value setting as I have explained in my above comment

Comment: @AshwinBalajiKuppuraj you keep repeating yourself and so do I - **break out of the loop**.

Comment: @WeatherVane Can you please explain how i can put a break

Comment: No, it is elementary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a couple of mistakes

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    char ch1, ch2;
    for (int i=i; i<=20; i++) {
        int a = rand () % 20;
        cout << "The number is: " << a << endl;
        ch2 = 'y';
        //You only need to loop until its square root; after that is repetition
        for (int l=2; l<=sqrt(a); l++) {
            //You need to break if a divisor is found, else it is always going to say it's prime
            if (a%l==0){
                ch2 = 'n';
                break;
            }
        }

        cout << ch2 << endl;
        cout << "Enter 'y' if number is prime else 'n'" << endl;
        cin >> ch1;
        if (ch1 != ch2) {
            cout << "You lost" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I also did some cleanup of your code

Answer (score 0):

May be this one helps

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int n, i;
  char res='y';
  char ans;
  n =rand( ) % 20;
  cout << "The Number is:" << n << endl;

  for(i = 2; i <= n / 2; ++i)
  {
      if(n % i == 0)
      {
          res='n';
          break;
      }
  }
  cout << "Enter 'y' if it is a prime number and 'n' if it is a non-prime number"<< endl;
  cin >> ans;
  ans = tolower(ans);

  if (ans==res)
  {cout << "You win";}
  else 
  {cout << "You Lost";}

  return 0;
}
```